# How to Initialize Values to a HashSet<String[,]> in C#

Tags: c#, initialization, hashset

I am using VS 2008 and I need to know how to initialize the HashSet. I know Some values which is needed to add it during initialization. How can I add values to the tblNames.

```
System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<String[,]> tblNames;
            tblNames = new System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<string[,]>();

tblNames.Add(new String[0,0] {"tblCategory","CatName" ,}); // this is showing Error..
```

The ultimate aim is to prevent user from entering duplicate values.I need to check it from different forms and from different tables and different fields.I go for querying the database using a dynamic query. I need to store the table name and column name in some index,value,value format `for eg My tablename is tblCategory and field name is CatName`.So I will store the value in the way`0,tblCategory,CatName`. So I will use Ajax to a handler page and in that I am using the above code.Here I am passing `0` to get the `first value[tablename and column name]`,1 for another table and field and so on. So I thought of using this way.

Whether I am using the correct way or any other way to achieve the aim ie  to prevent user from entering duplicate values ?

Thanks ,Harie

Comment: I hope you're aware that you're only going to get *reference* equality on the 2D arrays this way - so the set will treat different arrays with the same elements as different. If that's the intention, great. Otherwise, you'll probably have to write your own `IEqualityComparer<T>` implementation, and get the set to use that instead

Comment: Do you *really* need a set of 2-dimensional arrays of strings? I can't think of a single time I used multidimensional string arrays since I programmed in BASIC in the '80s. I suspect that what you actually want is a different data structure. If you tell us your purpose maybe we can offer a better suggestion.

Comment: thnks for ur answers and pls see my updated question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
tblNames.Add(new [,] { { "0", "tblAssetCategory" }});
```

Answer (score 22):

I want to write [java](/questions/tagged/java) code and assume that it is the same as in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)

```
HashSet<T> tblNames = new HashSet<T>(); // T should be same

HashSet<string> tblNames = new HashSet<string> ();
tblNames.add("a");
tblNames.add("b");
tblNames.add("c");
```

or simply

```
HashSet<string> tblNames = new HashSet<string> {"a", "b", "c"};
```

or

```
HashSet<String[,]> tblNames = new HashSet<String[,]> ();
// same logic you can add array here
tblNames.add(stringArray1);
tblNames.add(stringArray2);
```

or again

```
HashSet<String[,]> tblNames = new HashSet<String[,]> {stringArray1, strginArray2};
```

Answer (score 17):

If you want to initialize the `HashSet` with a set of known values in one step, you can use code similar to the following:

```
HashSet<string[,]> tblNames;
string[,] stringOne = new string[1, 1];
string[,] stringTwo = new string[1, 1];

tblNames = new HashSet<string[,]> { stringOne, stringTwo };
```

This is called a **collection initializer**. It was introduced in C# 3.0, and includes the following elements:

- A sequence of object initializers, enclosed by `{` and `}` tokens and separated by commas.
- Element initializers, each of which specifies an element to be added to the collection object.

Comment: Note that the element type is a 2D array of strings.

Comment: @Ani: Yeah, it works the same way. Still, it'd be better if I payed closer attention to the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

To initialize and assign values to a HashSet in one line, we can do something like this:

`var set = new HashSet<string>() { "some value1", "some value2" };`

In C#, this is considered using an object initializer and can be read about in MSFT docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-objects-by-using-an-object-initializer